# I can't find a tag called windows-8. Would such a tag be useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is the `uefi` tag but I feel a `windows-8` tag would be more "friendly". In any case, there are tags for Win 7 and XP.
I feel it could be useful for questions possibly arising from difficulties faced in dual-booting.

Edit: I felt quite stupid after it was pointed out that the windows-8 tag exists. But these two images may explain why I thought it didn't:

[image]

Note that I had typed just `win` and there was no windows-8 tag.

But when I type `wind` I see it:  [image]

Answer (score 5):

Actually, we already have a [windows-8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-8) [tag](https://askubuntu.com/tags/windows-8/info) with 183 questions posted in it.

Comment: My bad. I'm sorry I didn't look carefully!

Answer (score 3):

Tags are not "created" simply because they should exist. Rather, they are created when an appropriate question is asked that uses the tag for the first time.

Therefore your question becomes:

> "Should existing questions be retagged [windows8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows8)?"

This should be determined on a question-by-question basis. If the question *only* applies to Windows 8 (and no other Windows versions) than it may be a good candidate.